# rgrass7 init error

Tags: r, grass-gis, rgrass7

I am using `rgrass7` with R and by typing the following

```
initGRASS(gisBase = "C:/GRASS/GRASS_GIS_7_3_svn", 
home=tempdir(), gisDbase = "C:/Users/main/Desktop/data",
location = "Thesis",mapset = "user", override = T)
```

I get this error

> Error in if (get("SYS", envir = .GRASS_CACHE) == "WinNat" && nchar(WN_bat) ==  : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Now I was wandering if anyone else had the same problem at some point and knows how to prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

I have spent 3 hours trying to solve this weird issue. Initiating the exact same GRASS session that was working the day before, then I closed RStudio, and next time it was simply not working.

I found the issue has something to do with not finding/reading the GRASS_CACHE in the system environment path. Checked the windows path and it was not the issue.

I just **restarted** the computer and it was just fixed. I guess it has something to do with adding/removing the existing grass cache form the memory.

Comment: Yeah, turns out that GRASS doesn't like R. Meaning that every time you have to work with R and GRASS you have to make sure that the cache is clear, or that you should restart your PC. That is a problem with the library because parsing commands from GRASS in R is rather confusing for R but executing Rscript in GRASS is easier.

Comment: Restarting R session within RStudio helps too.